# GCP: From an organization level, can I control which GCS buckets are reachable from on-prem?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-networking

The situation is thus:
I have hybrid connectivity, I'm on the on-prem network, and I'm going to move a file over a VPN into a Cloud Storage bucket via [Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access-hybrid).  But, I'm malicious.  I've decided to send that file to a bucket which is not *owned* by my organization.  How can my organization prevent me from doing this?

I suspect that I could use a [VPC Service Control](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/overview) to create a perimeter around my VPN project and the project with the good bucket.  But is this the best/only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By configuration, VPC Service Control is the only way to do this. VPC Service Control is particularly well design for [data exfiltration](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/overview#benefits).

Else, you have to build a proxy by yourselves and to check each request and validate that they reach only a bucket inside your organisation.